# Flutter. Icon button does not work How can I get the button to work?

Tags: flutter

I made an icon button, it looks good on Chrome, but it doesn't work even if I click it.

I'm trying to create a motivational app.
I tried to show the proverbs in the middle of the screen, and I tried to show another proverbs by pressing the button, but the button didn't respond.
I don't know what I did wrong

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:app/count_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      home:ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) =>  CountPage()
        ,child: Quote() ,)
      );
  }
}

class Quote extends StatelessWidget {
  Quote({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  late CountPage _countPage;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context,listen: false);
    String arrayText = '[{"author": "-공자-","message": "멈추지 않으면 얼마나 천천히 가는지는 문제가 되지 않느니라 " },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "어디를 가든지 마음을 다해 가라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "상처는 잊되, 은혜는 결코 잊지 말라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "한 사람에게서 모든 덕을 구하지 말라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "허물이 있다면, 버리기를 두려워 말라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "절약하지 않는 자는 고통받게 될 것이니라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "앞날을 결정짓고자 한다면 옛것을 공부하라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "지나침은 모자람만 못하다" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "스스로 존경하면 다른 사람도 그대를 존경할 것이니라" },'
        '{"author": "공자","message": "흠 없는 조약돌보다는 흠 있는 금강석이 더 나으니라" },'
        '{"author": "나폴레옹","message": "내 사전에 불가능은 없다" },'
        '{"author": "바이런","message": "가장 뛰어난 예언자는 과거이다" },'
        '{"author": "나폴레옹","message": "내 비장의 무기는 아직 손안에 있다" },'
        '{"author": "소크라테스","message": "너 자신을 알라" },'
        '{"author": "아리스토텔레스","message": "많은 벗을 가진 사람은 한 사람의 진실한 벗을 가질 수 없다" },'
        '{"author": "솔론","message": "말은 행동의 거울이다." },'
        '{"author": "플랭클린","message": "백 년을 살 것처럼 일하고" },'
        '{"author": "아리스토텔레스","message": "불행은 진정한 친구가" },'
        '{"author": "생텍쥐베리","message": "사막이 아름다운 것은 어딘가에 샘을 숨기고 있기 때문이다" },'
        '{"author": "파스칼","message": "습관은 제2의 천성으로 제1의 천성을 파괴한다" }]'; 
    List list = jsonDecode(arrayText);


    return Scaffold(
      body:Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Center(child: IconButton(onPressed:(){_countPage.page_down();} , icon:Icon(Icons.chevron_left))),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 250,
                      child: Center(child: Text(list[_countPage.page]["message"],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40,color: Colors.black),textAlign: TextAlign.center,))
                  ),
                ),
                Center(child: Text(list[_countPage.page]["author"],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.black),)),
              ],
            ),
            Center(child: IconButton(onPressed:(){_countPage.page_up();}, icon:Icon(Icons.chevron_right))),
          ],
        ),
      ) ,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Center(child: IconButton(onPressed: copy, icon:Icon(Icons.settings))),
              Center(child: IconButton(onPressed: share, icon:Icon(Icons.content_copy))),
              Center(child: IconButton(onPressed: option, icon:Icon(Icons.share))),
            ],

          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  void copy() {
  }

  void share() {
  }

  void option() {
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CountPage extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _page = 0;
  int get page => _page;

   page_down() {
    _page --;
    notifyListeners();
  }

   page_up() {
    _page ++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is my first time to ask a stack overflow and I am an inexperienced developer.
If there's anything wrong with my questioning method and code, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me without hesitation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are not listening to changes to the provider, so the value of `_countPage` doesn't change when you notify the listeners.
Try changing

```
_countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context,listen: false);
```

to

```
_countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context,listen: true);
```

Comment: I solved the problem well.
Thank you so much for giving up your time for my problem.